# How can I get this menu container to be the height of the contents?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu that was created using Bootstrap 4.  I am using CSS to show all sub menus on the opening of the main li (Products).  Everything is working as expected however the container is not recognizing that the the nested submenu is open and therefore not adapting to the correct height. The staging website is http://bgp.captchaintherye.com.  I'm looking to get the container (#main-menu) to adapt in height to include the sub menus.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though it was as simple as making those nested drop downs relative position and setting top to 0.